# What are "Forms" in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, activex

I'm trying to add a legacy ActiveX control (a radio button) to a Word Document in Microsoft Office 2010, but when I select it from the Controls section of the Developer tab, I am prompted with this message:

> The program used to create this object is Forms. That program is either not installed on your computer or is not responding. To edit this object, install Forms or ensure that any dialog boxes in Forms are closed.

[image]

This sounds like a sensible requirement to me, but I can't find this "Forms" program anywhere on my computer or online... not even a mention of it. Microsoft's site and Google both have not yielded any fruitful results.

I should clarify that I have already attempted the fix suggested by Microsoft [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025036):

> When you insert a Forms ActiveX control (forms3) into a Microsoft Office document, or when you edit the properties of a control, you may receive an error message that resembles one of the following in an ActiveX custom Office solution [...]

<strike>I don't have the December 2014 update that kills ActiveX installed.</strike> I seem to have the problematic December 2014 update KB2553154 installed (when I try to download it from Microsoft and run it, it says it's already installed) even though I can't see it in my Installed Updates window.

I updated from Service Pack 1 to Service Pack 2 and that also did not solve the issue. I have not yet tried repairing/reinstalling.

What is this "Forms" program? Is it available for download/install somewhere?

Comment: "I do not have the update from December 2014 that breaks ActiveX installed on this computer".  You should install _all_ available Office updates (and all Windows security updates) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Turns out I do have KB2553154 but it is not visible in Installed Updates for some reason. At any rate, installing all the updates from that page don't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

MS has a KB on this topic: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025036

Apparently an update in 2014 (MS14-082), causes this issue. the MS advice is to install ALL windows update pertinent to your Office installation. There is a list for office 2010 in the KB.

Comment: I forgot that I had already tried that step when I asked the question (I'll edit the info in). I have already installed the KB updates for Office 2010 and Word 2010 listed in that article and the error persisted. I will install the rest for the applications I have installed (PPT, Excel, Access) and try again.